# Lyx A3 page in an A4 document

Tags: lyx, thesis, paper-size

I need to insert an A3 sized figure in my lyx document (my thesis chapter) is this possible? I have seen some on here around LaTex but not sure how to include it in lyx, I am new to it.

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be an answer at [this site](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/change-margins-of-a-single-page/), though it's not a LyX answer _per se_. You'll likely have to load the `geometry` package and use it to change the paper size.

Comment: @volc_nerd I think my answer is correct. Do you have any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

The solution referenced by Arun Debray's link is simple, maybe it is enough. It consists in typing explicit LaTeX-code `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` from the `geometry`. To make it work with a float, maybe one would need to combine it with the `afterpage` package. I could not manage to make it work though, so I'd be curious to see a proper answer using this method. In the meanwhile, here's a general solution for such problems where one needs to break from the standard page formatting, i.e. for the title page or special figure pages.

## How to have a page with a special format

A flexible and sometimes recommended solution depending on the purpose is to generate your figure in a separate PDF with the desired page formatting, and use the package `pdfpages` to include the page. This can be used for special figures, either generated with LaTeX or not.

LyX supports PDF Pages via Insert > External Material. Then the idea is that you create your figure in a separate LyX document, or with any other pdf-producing software (Inkscape...).

You want the included page to retain its format. For this, set the option `fitpaper` (and not `noautoscale`). Other useful options include:

- `pages={1}`: only include the first page from the pdf
- `pagecommand={}`: keep the page numbering (not useful when the paper size is different because the page number is improperly placed, except maybe in combination with the `landcape` option)
- `addtolist={1,figure,{My Figure},myreflabel}`: add an entry to the list of figures with text ''My Figure'' and a reference myreflabel.

Refer to the pdfpages manual for more options.